# Django : import a module

Tags: python, django, import

I'm trying to control a LED with a raspberry pi from a Django application.
I wrote a python script to set the color of the LED and everything is okey.
However when I call the script from my views.py I got an AttributeError : module has no attribute.

**Views.py**

```
import sys, os
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/lampe/scripts'))
import launcher, lampe

"""Vue utilisee pour appliquer une couleur"""
class Appliquer_couleur(View):
  def get(self, context, **reponse_kwargs):
    print(self.kwargs['pk'])
    couleur_serialized = CouleurSerializer(Couleur.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']))
    launcher.launch(couleur_serialized.data['code'])
    return HttpResponse('')
```

In the directory "lampe/static/lampe/scripts" I have three files :
an empty **init**.py, lampe.py and launcher.py

**Lampe.py**

```
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
def setCouleur(arg1):
  ..
```

**Launcher.py**

```
import sys, os
from multiprocessing import Process

import lampe as LED

def launch(arg1):
  try:
    process = Process(target=LED.setCouleur, args=(arg1,))
    process.start()
    process.join()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

if __name__== "__main__":
  sys.exit(launch(sys.argv[1]))
```

**Traceback**

```
Internal Server Error: /lampe/appliquer_couleur/1/
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pyrotecnix/Projet/aurore/lampe/views.py", line 85, in get
launcher.launch(couleur_serialized.data['code'])
File "/home/pyrotecnix/Projet/aurore/lampe/static/lampe/scripts/launcher.py", line 9, in launch
process = Process(target=LED.setCouleur, args=(arg1,))
AttributeError: module 'lampe' has no attribute 'setCouleur'
[16/May/2016 17:29:00] "GET /lampe/appliquer_couleur/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 69516
```

Comment: Post edited with the traceback

Comment: in `launcher.py` or `views.py` can you try `print(LED.__file__)` to see what `lampe` module is being imported?  You might be importing a the `static/lampe` folder or the project folder as a package by accident.

Comment: is `target=LED.setCouleur` correct? You sure that it isn't supposed to be `target=LED.setCouleur()? Normally setters and getters are functions AFAIK, but perhaps this is as intended.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen : I add the line in views.py and I got a nameError : name LED is not defined.

SeanM : I think it's correct since when I launch launcher.py directly it works.

Comment: can you get rid of the second import of `lampe` in views.py and try again?

Comment: sorry, `LED.__file__` from launcher.py or `lampe.__file__` from views.py (you import the same file with two different names?)

Comment: I've deleted the second import. Now I have "import launcher"
The print return nothing

Comment: Please restore your second import, then within the try except block of launcher.py AND within your view, insert a `print(dir(LED))` and `print(dir(lampe))` respectively. Rerun and report stdout

Comment: View : 

['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'admin', 'forms', 'models', 'serializers']

Launcher :

['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'admin', 'forms', 'migrations', 'models', 'serializers', 'urls', 'views']

Comment: the name of your project "lampe" is concealing the "lampe.py" in lampe/static/lampe/scripts please rename your lampe.py and try again.

Comment: It works ! I change lampe.py in lampe_script.py
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the name of your project "lampe" is concealing the "lampe.py" in lampe/static/lampe/scripts as it is being found by python and importing it before importing the 'lampe.py' module. please rename your lampe.py and try again.